# Keep getting the error 'TypeError: events.map is not a function'

Tags: javascript, api, rest, next.js, strapi

I'm very new to **Next.js** & **Strapi** & I've been stuck on this issue for 2 days.

My index pages are accessing and fetching data from my **Strapi V4** **api** backend but my detail pages/**[slug].js** keep getting the error 'events.map is not a function'.
As well as other errors when I try to workaround the problem.

This is my **[slug].js**

```
export default function EventPage({ evt }) {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <div className={classes.container}>
                <GridContainer>
                    <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={6} >
                        <Card blog>
                            <CardHeader image>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img key={evt.id}
                                        src={evt.image.formats.medium.url
                                        ? evt.attributes.image.data.attributes.formats.medium.url
                                        : '/img/image.webp'}
                                        alt="..." 
                                    />
                                </a>
                            </CardHeader>
                            <CardBody>
                                <Info>
                                    <h6 className={classes.cardCategory}>{ evt.name }</h6>
                                </Info>
                                <div className={classes.cardDescription}>
                                    { evt.description }
                                </div>
                            </CardBody>
                        </Card>
                    </GridItem>
                </GridContainer>
            </div>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}events`)
    const events = await res.json()
  
    const paths = events.map((evt) => ({
      params: { slug: evt.slug },
    }))
  
    return {
      paths,
      fallback: true,
    }
}
  
  
export async function getStaticProps({ params: { slug } }) {
    const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}events?slug=${slug}`)
    const events = await res.json()
  
    return {
      props: {
        evt: events[0],
      },
      revalidate: 1,
    }
}
```

I know all of you are busy like I am so I really appreciate the help.

Comment: have you checked that it is an array?

Comment: Have you checked what the value of `events` is?

Comment: when I console.log(events) - I get {
  data: [
    { id: 1, attributes: [Object] },
    { id: 2, attributes: [Object] },
    { id: 3, attributes: [Object] }
  ],
  meta: { pagination: { page: 1, pageSize: 25, pageCount: 1, total: 3 } }
}

Comment: will this work? const {data} = events

Comment: if i use events.data.map i get 'Error: A required parameter (slug) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /events/[slug]'

Answer (score 0):

Strapi API now returns an object, not an array. Inside that object is a data array you can loop through with map(), so you need to destructure it:

```js
 const { data } = await res.json();
```

[you can see the API returns an object at the top level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFkX8.png)